# The invertability of a differential and it's matrix representation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am self-studying Lee's Introduction To Smooth Manifolds, and I want to make sure I am understanding a point correctly. When discussing the differential $dF_{p}:T_{p} \rightarrow T_{F(p)}N$ of a smooth function between manifolds, there is a nice characterization of it's matrix representation, which is given by the following:

If $(U, \gamma)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are charts such that $p \in U$, $F(U)\subseteq V$, and

$\hat{F}=\psi \, \circ F \, \circ \gamma^{-1} : \gamma(U \cap F^{-1}(V)) \rightarrow \psi(V)  $

is smooth, then the matrix representation of $d_{p}F$ is given by the Jacobian of $\hat{F}$ evaluated at $\psi(p)$, or $D\hat{F}(\psi(p))$.

Now, my question is the following: We know that a linear map is invertible if and only if it's matrix representation is. I would like to apply the same logic to the above to the linear map $d_{p}F$, but it seems that it's matrix representation was dependent on the charts we began with. Is it true that $d_{p}F$ is invertible if and only if $D\hat{F}(\psi(p))$ is, regardless of the charts we choose?

Comment: Yes, it is. The reason is that if you change charts, your new matrix for $d_PF$ is obtained by multiplying the old one by the Jacobian Matrix of the coordinate change (or its inverse) from both sides. Both Jacobian matrices are invertible, hence the new matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true that $d_pF$ is invertible if and only if $D\widehat{F}(\psi(p))$ is, by very much the same reason as to why a linear map is invertible if and only if a given matricial representation of it is. The expression of $d_pF$ as a matrix (the Jacobian) given charts $\gamma, \psi$ is just the expression of the linear map $d_pF$ with respect to the bases $(\partial_i(\cdot \circ \gamma^{-1}))_{i=1,\cdots ,n}$ and $(\partial_i(\cdot \circ \psi^{-1}))_{i=1,\cdots ,n}$ of $T_pM$ and $T_{F(p)}N$, respectively.

The fact that the matrix depends on the choice of charts is just a result of the fact that different charts furnish different associated bases of the tangent spaces. The situation is just plain linear algebra, the charts are just used in order to choose the bases.

Comment: Would another way to say it be the following: Because the invertibility of $d_{p}F$ is independent of the choice of charts, its must be the case that the matrix representation is invertible regardless of the choice of charts?

Comment: @Mark Yes, but that is the case because what you call "matrix representation" is *the matrix representation* of the linear map $d_pF$ w.r.t some basis, in the sense of linear algebra. That's why it is best to understand that this is linear algebra only. The charts are almost a red herring, they are just a means of obtaining bases for the vector spaces involved.